# Graceful Labeling for cycle

Tags: graph-theory

This result has been proved by Rosa, but I can't find a link to see his paper. I want to show that the graph $C_n$ is graceful if and only if $n=4k$ or $n=4k-1$ for some integer $k$.

It's not hard to prove the necessary condition using parity argument. 
I haven't find the idea to construct the labeling.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to get you started:

If $n=4k$, assign the sequence $(0,1,2,\ldots, 2k-1)$ to every other vertex. Next find a way to assign the sequences $(2k,2k+1,\ldots,3k-1)$ and $(3k+1,3k+2,\ldots,4k)$ to the remaining vertices.

If $n=4k-1$, then do something similar as the previous case starting with $(2k+1,\ldots,4k-1)$ and then $(0,1,2,k-1)$ and $(k+1,k+2,2k)$.

As a bonus hint, note that in a graceful labelling, $0$ *must* be adjacent to $n$.

Comment: Casteels, thank you for the idea. Sorry, I still have a problem to construct the labelling from your idea

Answer (score 0):

I think the paper you are referring to might be:

On certain valuations of the vertices of a graph. (French summary) 1967 Theory of Graphs (Internat. Sympos., Rome, 1966) pp. 349–355 Gordon and Breach, New York; Dunod, Paris

For a good survey on graph labellings, also see:
Gallian, Joseph A.(1-MND-MS)
A dynamic survey of graph labeling. (English summary)
Electron. J. Combin. 5 (1998), Dynamic Survey 6, 43 pp. (electronic).